# I'm trying to append to a list in python but it gives back a NoneType

Tags: python, list, dataframe, nonetype

This is my code but my output gives a none type back and not a list full of numbers.

```
PHC=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    x=df['HC'][0:i+1].mean()
    PHC=PHC.append(x)
```

Comment: you want to append inside the loop if you are not doing so

Comment: Can you post more of the code? its hard to test and debug as it is.

Answer (score -2):

```
len[df]['HC']
```

instead of

```
len[df]
```